# SQL Server Configuration Manager shows 32 bit, but 64 bit was downloaded

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I recently downloaded and installed SQL Server 2012 Express on my system. The files were clearly labeled as 64 bit. There was not even an option to choose a 32 bit. The file was labeled as ENU\x64\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe. But now that I have downloaded it, the SQL Server Configuration Manager states that I have SQL Server Network Configuration (32 bit) and SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration (32 bit).

Is this supposed to be this way? Is there a configuration setting to change it to 64 bit?

Comment: Just looking at my config manager and there are no nodes under `SQL Server Network Configuration (32 bit)`. How about you? The _Native Client_ Configuration node refers to the client components (which have both 64 and 32 bit versions). If you want to confirm which version you installed, connect and run `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Same here. There are no items listed under Network Configuration for my system. I cannot find out what bit version I have. When I open the management studio it says I have 11.0.2100.60.

Comment: I told you how to find out - connect to it and run `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: It is a 64 bit. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration Manager allows you to configure both 32-bit and 64-bit settings. That's why there are similar nodes in the MMC snap-in tree.

"Network Configuration" nodes contain settings for SQL Server instances on your machine. If you have no instances of a particular bitness on your machine, the corresponding node will be empty - ignore it.

"SQL Native Client ... Configuration" nodes, however, allow you to configure network protocols and instance aliases for **client applications** of a particular bitness. If you have 3rd party apps that connect to your SQL Server instances, check their bitness - you can see this in Task Manager, a 32-bit process will have a `*32` suffix after its name.

Most probably, you will need to configure both 32 and 64-bit versions of these nodes, as many apps are still 32-bit (especially the old ones).